# Bootstrap 3 - how to align a list to right of iframe

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create this layout in bootstrap:

[image: layout]

I have the iframe place but I am having some trouble aligning the ul to the right of it.

Here is my iframe:

```html
 <iframe width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" class="video-iframe" src]="'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtube.videoId + '?rel=0' | safe" >
</iframe>
```

Here is my list of videos:

```html
<div class="right-list-videos">
  <div class="list-group">
    <span *ngFor="let youtube of _youtube$ | async; let i = index;">
      <a class="list-group-item" (click)="changeVideo(i)" >
        <div class="media" >
          <a class="media-left"  >
            <img class="media-object " src="{{youtube.thumbnail}}" width="140px" height="105px">
          </a>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">{{youtube.title}}}</h4>
            <div class="media-text">{{youtube.description}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>

    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using a media object to try and align the iframe and items but it did not work for me. What would be the best way to go about this issue be?

Comment: do you want window url to right or only specific container to right allign

Answer (score 0):

Using boostrap column can help. Putting elements inside grid system will help align elements.
First of all if you are using bootstrap put the iframe and UL on column item like this:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <iframe src="" id="video">
        <!-- Your Iframe inner -->
    </iframe>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="right-list-videos">
        <!-- Right list content -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then you can style them using CSS like this

```
#video {
    width: 100%;
}

.right-list-videos {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
```

Also make sure your Iframe is not having fixed width or height

Hope it gets clear
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try `float`.

Read more here:http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

In your case, You can just add `.right-list-videos{ float:right; }` in your css.

Or else the better option would be to use Bootstrap Grid system and let the video take `col-md-9` and the list take up `col-md-3`.